Gorm database-agnostic Where clause when using postgres requireing quoted table names
Gorm seems to be lacking a database agnostic way of restricting on joined tables, this only really becomes a problem when using multiple database structures which in my case isn't suitable. I feel like this is a basic feature so must be missing something in the documentation? Below is an example...
db.Joins("Role").Model(&models.User{}).Where("Role.Name = 'ADMIN'").Find(&adminUsers)

would result in the following sql when using the postgres driver
select * from "users" 
LEFT JOIN "roles" "Role" on "users"."role_id" = "Role"."id"
WHERE Role.name = 'ADMIN'

Current solution;
The current solution is to check the database driver and build an escaped query for it specifically when using postgres compared to other dialects.
var query 
if drivers.POSTGRES.MatchDatabase(db) {
    query = "\"Role\".name = 'ADMIN'"
} else {
    query = "Role.Name = 'ADMIN'"
}

Solutions I'd be happy with;

The ability to remove all quotations on the gorm postgres driver and have everything lower case.
The ability to define a singular where clause which will work across all database structures.

